# DIY Double Conversion Power Conditioner

Tags: ac, dc, generator, ups, diy

I'm trying to build an AC-DC-AC converter similar to how an online double conversion UPS works, but I have a few concerns as I have only basic electronics knowledge and no real qualifications.

I live in an area where we have occasional power outages that last long enough where we bring out a portable generator. However as it is a cheaper style generator, it produces fairly dirty power.

I have some servers and networking gear protected behind a regular UPS (APC SMT1500RM2U), however I am still concerned about the quality of the AC output of the generator. For instance, whenever a fridge or freezer compressor, or some other high load would kick on, the UPS would rapidly switch back and forth between AC and battery. I'm afraid this might damage the UPS over time.

Hence, I'm trying to build an AC-DC-AC converter using an HP power supply (e.g. HP DPS-1200FB - 12VDC/75A output at 120VAC), a pure sine-wave inverter, and a supercapacitor bank. The HP PSU would convert the dirty AC power into DC, the supercapacitors would act as a buffer to smooth the DC, and the inverter would provide clean AC to the UPS.

My main questions/concerns are:

- Does this even make sense to do? Is there something I am missing that would make this project much more complicated than I'm envisioning it?
- How will the PSU and the supercapacitors work? If the capacitors are empty, would the PSU see them as a short and risk damage? Would I need some additional circuitry to handle this?
- The capacitor bank ([something like this](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/385009953614)) appears to be 6x 2.7V 500F capacitors in series, each with some sort of resistor circuitry to burn off excess voltage. Will this suffice to keep them "balanced"? In theory, as I only have 12VDC, each capacitor should only ever see a maximum of 2V, well below their limit. However, is there a possibility they could get so out of balance that one of them reaches above 2.7V and potentially blows up? I doubt the resistors can safely burn off more than 1A, let alone 75A.
- How long could I expect the capacitor bank to power the inverter? Assuming the inverter's low voltage cut-off is at 11V, meaning each capacitor ranges between 1.8V and 2V?

Comment: Well, a lot of extra hardware to feed the UPS and starting into empty capacitors may be a problem, but such a system could help to bridge a gap of some seconds. I would probably wait until the UPS failes the first time. Try to ask the manufacturer how many cycles you can expect.

Comment: How much power in total do you need to deliver to your load(s)? Also, do you have any control over when loads with large inrush currents (compressor motors) will start, and can you sequence them?  Or do you need to size the power output for worst case all loads starting all at once?

Answer (score 2):

### Supercaps are cool, but not practical.

The unique traits that make them different from batteries are useless to this application.  That makes them a very, very, very, very expensive way to get an inexpensive battery.  For instance your 83F (not 500F; they're *in series*) capacitor @ 12V is 1000 coulumbs or about 0.27 AH or 3.2 watt-hours, *the useful energy of an AA battery*.

*But wait, it's much worse!* A real battery has a narrow working range, hypothetically 12.5V at full and 11.0V at empty. The inverter can work at its full range. But a capacitor is 12.0V at full and 0.0V at empty!  *Whoops!*  So you'd only *be able to use* 10% of its capacity before it drops below input minimums for the inverter.   So now 0.32 watt-hours.

By contrast, lithium batteries are now under **25 cents** USD a watt-hour: You can walk into a Nissan dealer and go to the service desk, ask for a 62,000 watt-hour battery for a Leaf, *no core exchange* and it's yours for $15,000.   So 25 cents a watt-hour *at DEALER prices*.  Nevermind the fact that you'd never do that; you'd buy a wreck at an auction for a fraction of that, and get all the supporting equipment, connectors and a matching 6600W battery charger as part of the deal. ([the charger is on the car](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y)).   This is a *completely bonkers* game-changer for "whole house" battery backup.

### Build your own battery pack...

Anyway, back to your situation.  If you want the ultracap "cool" without the 5 second runtime, look into any of these options:

- the guys building large battery packs out of stacked 18650s pulled from equipment e.g. medical equipment batteries get swapped pretty frequently. The little battery testers, spot welders and nickel strips are readily available. Make sure you're "on your game" with balancing and BMS, though - mess those up and you get a fire!
- Building a pack by stacking modules pulled from EV wrecks. Lots of people are doing that too, and you can get aftermarket BMS's, balancers etc. ready to go.  Someone even makes a kit to turn a stack of Nissan Leaf blades into a portable pack!  The Leaf blades are nominally 8V each, so 3 stacks to ~24 volts, a common voltage for home power/inverters.

### ... and then, no more UPS. (it *is* a UPS).

Since sheer practicality forces you into a battery *anyway*... why not just make the pack bigger? Now two really cool things happen: #1 you don't need the UPS anymore **since this is one**, and #2 since you're doing AC-DC-AC *all the time* (similar to the high quality "online UPS"), you are fully isolated from utility-side power quality problems.

Getting rid of the UPS also unchains you from the cheap, short-lived batteries they typically use in consumer UPS's.  I'm sure you don't enjoy replacing UPS batteries every few years. These modern lithiums, especially the automotive-grade ones, are so good that'll stop happening.